# SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT in Django forwarding traffic to localhost

Tags: python, django

I have introduced SSL in my website, and I need make redirection from HTTP to HTTPS. I have website on Django 1.4.5.

I have installed djangosecure package using pip and added to settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
....,
'djangosecure.middleware.SecurityMiddleware',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
....
'djangosecure',
)

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

but now when when I'm trying open website I have redirection to https://127.0.0.1:8756 instead of my domain with https.

Answer (score 0):

localhost directly not support https connection.
You have to configure  "self-signed" cert,and configure server like(apache, nginx) with https connection.

follow below great article on this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thank you NeErAj for the answer, but I have running this website on server, not on my localhost, and I have bought Rapid SSL certificate for this server.